# what if android has no GPU and view calls setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE,null) ?

Tags: android, animation

i have a simple fading and rotating animation done through a object animator. Nothing fancy but to increase
performance with caching i wanted to use a hardware layer on the view itself. so before the animation begins
i call `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE,null);`
and after the animation is cancelled i call `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE,null)`;.
My question is what if the user does not have a GPU to render the animation for me ? will my app crash, this 
animation is for my splash screen so its very important that it never crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html):

> LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE: The view is rendered in hardware into a hardware
>   texture if the application is hardware accelerated. If the application
>   is not hardware accelerated, this layer type behaves the same as
>   LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE.